# How to count div's of one class, that are children of container div's of one class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to count the number of ('.child') in each container and append a sentence with the count inside each container.

```
<div class='container'>
     <div class='child'></div>
     <div class='child'></div>
     <div class='child'></div>
     <div class='child'></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
     <div class='child'></div>
     <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

How would you do that? Would you need id's or can it be done with just classes?
I want to find a clean way of doing it.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.container').each(function(i, obj){
    var children = $(this).find('.child').length;
    $('<p>' + children + ' elements.</p>').appendTo( $(this) );
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. That did it for me. What about "i" and "obj"? They are not used. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. The two arguments passed to the function argument in `$.fn.each` are (1) the index number and (2) the element being operated on (which is equivalent to `this`). I really only included them out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

use .length to get count of its source

example...

```
alert($('.container').children().length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that should handle what you are looking for

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.container').each(function(){
            var count=0,child=$(this).find('.child');
            if(child.length>0) {
                count++;
                child.each(function(){
                    $(this).text('This is child number '+count);
                    count++;
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cK8g/)

You don't need additional thing give the above html structure

```
  $('.container').each(function(){

    $(this).prepend('<label> No of children:'
                    +$(this).find('div.child').size()
                    +'</label>');
  });
```